# Tomcat8 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper

Tags: tomcat8

I am upgrading a reporting application which comes with Tomcat bundled with the package.. Recently i upgraded latest version which contains Tomcat8, during upgrade did not see any errors or failures,it was completed successfully but after the upgrade not able to start Tomcat.. (earlier version was tomcat7)
I see following error in stderr:

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1178)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1344)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:857)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:444)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:490)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue .....

Comment: @Raj Did you ever solve this?

Comment: It was resolved.. Actually i was having SSL configured and some security setup done on Tomcat, before upgrade i replaced the server.xml from the backup(File before custom changes) and then started the upgrade. after the upgrade it came up fine..